# ¿como Validar contenido de TextBox con patron?

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

Valido con el siguiente método en C# con una ventana WPF un texto que solo debe aceptar nombres validos, al igual que aceptar 2 nombres pero no mas, como por ejemplo los siguientes:

Ejemplos correctos:

- **Alejandro**
- **Richard Yordy**

Ejemplos Erroneos:

- **2Alejandro24**
- **Teresa de jesus**

Código

```
  if (e.Key == Key.Delete || e.Key == Key.Back)
            {
                if (tbNombre.Text.Length >= 1|| tbNombre.Text.Length  ==0)
                {
                    nombre = tbNombre.Text;
                }
            }
            else if (Regex.IsMatch(tbNombre.Text, "^([a-zA-Z]{1,10}[ ]?[a-zA-Z]{0,7})$"))
            {
                nombre = tbNombre.Text;
            }
            else if (tbNombre.Text.Length != 0)
            {
                tt.Content = "No se aceptan numeros";
                tbNombre.ToolTip = tt;
                tt.IsOpen = true;
                int cursor = tbNombre.SelectionStart;
                tbNombre.Text = nombre;
                timer.Tick += new EventHandler(delegate (object timerSender, EventArgs timerArgs)//Para desaparecer el tooltip en un determinado tiempo
                {
                    tt.IsOpen = false;

                });
                if (cursor >= 0)
                {
                    if (cursor == 0)
                    {
                        tbNombre.SelectionStart = cursor;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tbNombre.SelectionStart = cursor - 1;
                    }
                }

            }
```

Lo soluciono de esta manera lo cual valida con forme se escribe para evitar que se ingresen datos inválidos como lo son los números.. Quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de mejorar esto para implementarlo en otros TextBox

Comment: El codigo que diste es una guia de lo que quieres o es un ejemplo que no funciona? Lo digo porque no se relaciona con lo que pides.

Comment: El código que esta ahí es el que uso para validar un campo mediante el evento **keyUp**  el cual cada ves que  se preciona una tecla valida el contendió de un **TextBox** usando una **expresión regular**

Comment: Richard, para que tu pregunta sea mas clara, intenta agregar un ejemplo de que dato deberia de ser incorrecto o correcto. Intenta tambien organizar tu idea. Cuando dices *'quiero quiero que acepte lo alguna palabra con espacio'* en realidad confundes porque no sabemos exactamente cuales son esas palabras que *quieres* que se acepten.

Comment: En que parte del código es en la que intentas borrar el texto del tbUsuario?.

Y que está pasando con el else?

Comment: El título de la pregunta habla de cómo validar un texto con un patrón. Pero luego leyendo el contenido parece que el problema lo tienes borrando un texto. ¿Cuál es el problema? Por favor, podrías editar el título y la pregunta para que quede más claro? Si la validación con la expresión regular te funciona, quizás deberías omitirlo en la pregunta y centrarte donde tienes el problema

Comment: Por qué "Teresa de Jesus" es erróneo? Parece un nombre perfectamente válido.

Comment: @Julio por que para el ejemplo se busca validar aquellos nombres que solo tienen dos nombres pero sin palabras extras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mayor problema que le veo a tu expresión regular es que es un poco inconsistente. Me explico.

Por un lado, si escribes nombres y apellido, la longitud máxima del nombre es 10 y la del apellido es 7.

Por otro lado, si tienes un nombre sin apellido, permites nombres de hasta 17 caracteres (haciendo el espacio opcional y añadiendo el tamaño del apellido al nombre)

Tendría más sentido que la longitud máxima del nombre fuera consistente e independiente de si se ha introducido un apellido o no.

Una expresión regular para lograrlo sería esta:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2,10}(?: [a-zA-Z]{2,10})?$
```

(ajusta los tamaños del nombre y apellidos a tu conveniencia)